# Get the second element of a list of lists as a list of lists

Tags: racket

I'm learning Racket and I want to get the second list of a list of lists, not as a list of a list of lists.

I have this list of lists:

```
(define list-of-list '(((a b c) (d e f)) ((1 2 3) (4 5 6))))
```

If I do:

```
(car list-of-list)
```

I get:

```
> '((a b c) (d e f))
```

But, if I do:

```
(cdr list-of-list)
```

I get:

```
> '(((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
```

I have also tried:

```
(list-tail list-of-list 1)
```

But I get a list of a list of lists:

```
>'(((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
```

The only way to get what I want is doing:

```
(cadr list-of-list)
> '((1 2 3) (4 5 6))
```

I think this is the right working way of Racket, but, because I'm learning:

Is there a better (or functional programming style) way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the correct way, but this is easier to read:

```
(second list-of-list)
=> '((1 2 3) (4 5 6))
```

In case you're wondering, there is also `third` and `fourth` and so on up until `tenth`. It's all in the [docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html).

Answer (score 0):

Can I recommend either "The Little Schemer" (amusing, short, thought-provoking) or "How To Design Programs" (free on the web at HtDP.org, long and detailed, textbook-ish)?  Both are well-written by experts. In fact, one expert appears in the author list of both books.